# Why extend function save character by character?

Tags: python

I know this is very simple question but I can't find any answer. My code is:

```
f = []
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(opts.sourcedirectory):
    for name in filenames:
        fullsourcefilename = os.path.join(opts.sourcedirectory, name)
        print '\n'+fullsourcefilename
        f.extend(fullsourcefilename)
        break
    print "it is finished"
    for fileo in f:
       print '\n'+fileo
    exit()
```

First print (**fullsourcefilename**) is OK and show the full path of the files but the second have some output like this:

```
d
e
x
.
h
t
m
l
```

I don't know what to do with it. How can I correct it?

Comment: You're looking for `f.append`, I think? `f.extend` extends `f` with the iterable provided, since the string is an iterable and the 1 length strings inside are the elements of the iterable, the function extends `f` with the characters.

Comment: @SukritKalra Yes you are right

Comment: @Shombol-shagol If really want `.extend` you could use `.extend([data])`, this initially wrap `data` in list.

Comment: @Alexei Yes i want that.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `f.extend(fullsourcefilename)` to `f.append(fullsourcefilename)`.

[`append(x)`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/array.html#array.array.append) will "append a new item with value x to the end of the array."

[`extend(iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/array.html#array.array.extend) will "append items from iterable to the end of the array. If iterable is another array, it must have exactly the same type code; if not, TypeError will be raised. If iterable is not an array, it must be iterable and its elements must be the right type to be appended to the array."

A simple example of `append` is:

```
initial_list = [1, 2, 3]
initial_list.append(4)      # initial_list is now [1, 2, 3, 4]
initial_list.append([5, 6]) # initial_list is now [1, 2, 3, 4, [5, 6]]
```

A simple example for `extend` is:

```
initial_list = [1, 2, 3]
initial_list.extend(4)      # TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
initial_list.extend([4, 5]) # initial_list is now [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
initial_list.extend([6])    #initial_list is now [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```